# Unable to create a SOAP Client object in ZF2

Tags: web-services, zend-framework, soap, wsdl, zend-framework2

I am creating a zend SOAP Client object to call the WSDL functions.

Here is my controller code :

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover;

use Zend\Soap\Client;

use Zend\Soap\Server;

use Zend\Soap\Wsdl;


class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {


$client = new Zend\Soap\Client("some.wsdl", array('compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT));

        $result = $client->somefunction();


        echo $result;
        echo exit;
    }
```

My library files are /vendor/ZF2/library/Zend.

And controller is modules folder.

I have used the Zend\Soap\Client; in controller.

Getting the following error: Fatal error: Class 'Application\Controller\Zend\Soap\Client' not found in .../Controller/IndexController.php on line 25

How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `use Zend\Soap\Client;` at the top of the file, you want:

```
$client = new Client("some.wsdl", array('compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT));
```